# C - monitoring the size of an array of structs without a global variable?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Basically I have a struct defined globally that will hold the best scoring elements of something:

```
int structlength = 0;

typedef char topscorer_t[MAX_INPUT + 1];

typedef struct {
    topscorer_t name;
    double score;
    int ID;
} top_scores;

top_scores scores[HIGHEST_SCORES + 1];
```

Unfortunately, my program works but will not receive full marks if I hand it in like this because every time a function adds a new struct to `scores` I also do `structlength += 1` to track how many elements are now in it, and `structlength` is a global variable; something my lecturer absolutely hates.

Is there another way I can track how many structs have been added to the array `scores`?

On a side note, is a struct defined this way also treated like a global variable? I'm very new to this :/

Comment: Arrays defined using `[]` syntax in C have a fixed-size at compile-time. I don't see you reallocating the array if you hit `HIGHEST_SCORES`, are you writing into unallocated memory?

Comment: @Dai yes. I'm not even good enough yet to use `malloc()`

Comment: You do need to explicitly keep track of the number of structs you have in your array if it varies during the lifetime of your program.

Comment: @AnirudhRamanathan does this mean I'll have to incorporate `malloc()`?

Comment: It would be better if you did, because here, you may overflow the bounds of the array you allocate at compile-time, but having to maintain the variable tracking the number of elements is still needed. If you really want to avoid the global, create the array within main (or some other function) and pass a pointer around to every function that uses it. In terms of readability, sometimes, what you currently have may be the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate things in another `struct`. Note I prefer `calloc` to `malloc`.

```
struct ScoreEntry {
    wchar_t* name;
    double   score;
    int      id;
};

struct List {
    struct ScoreEntry buffer[]; // Note this an array-of-struct rather than array-of-ptr-to-struct
    size_t            bufferLength;
    size_t            bufferIndex;
};

List* List_create(size_t initialLength) {
    struct List* ret = calloc( 1, sizeof(struct List) );
    if( ret == NULL ) exit(1);
    ret->buffer = calloc( initialLength, sizeof(struct ScoreEntry) );
    if( ret->buffer == NULL ) exit(1);
    ret->bufferLength = initialLength;
    return ret;
}

void List_delete(struct List* list) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < list->bufferIndex; i++ ) {
        free( list->buffer[i].name );
    }
    free( list->buffer );
    free( list );
}

void List_add(struct List* list, struct ScoreEntry entry) {
    if( list->bufferIndex >= list->bufferLength ) {
        // Reallocate buffer using `calloc`
        if( true ) {
            size_t newLength = 2 * list->bufferLength;
            struct ScoreEntry* newBuffer = calloc( newLength , sizeof(struct ScoreEntry) );
            if( newBuffer == NULL ) exit(1);
            memcpy( newBuffer, list->buffer, list->bufferIndex );
            free( list->buffer );
        } else {
            // Or reallocate with `realloc`
            list->buffer = realloc( list->buffer, newLength );
            if( list->buffer == NULL ) exit(1);
        }
        list->bufferLength = newLength;
    }
    list->buffer[ list->bufferIndex++ ] = entry; // note this is a copy operation
}
```

So in your program:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    struct List* scoresList = List_create( 10 );

    List_add( scoresList, { .name = L"Person 1", .score = 123, .id = 1 } ); // C99 struct initialization syntax
    List_add( scoresList, { .name = L"Person 2", .score = 456, .id = 2 } );
    List_add( scoresList, { .name = L"Person 3", .score = 789, .id = 3 } );

    List_delete( scoresList );
}
```

Note my example will fail as the strings are allocated at compile time and so cannot be freed. The solution to that would be to explicitly track if each `name` was a runtime or compile-time string and then call `free( name )` accordingly.

Comment: Woah, all that just to not use a global variable? Could static variables work? I'm having so much trouble trying to read that O_o

Comment: @Laefica in C, `static` doesn't mean what you think it does (it's effectively the same as a global, but with a limited scope). My posting demonstrates one of the main ideas of OOP: object encapsulation. My `List` structure encapsulates everything you need to know about the list in order to do anything with it (that's the idea of "state"), so no globals are needed, instead just pass the `List` instance where it's needed.

Comment: I'll use this as reference as I get deeper into C. Cheers.